# How can I solder a 2nd connection to a mini USB?

Tags: usb, soldering, communication

I have a device that utilizes a mini USB port to send and receive data. I am trying to figure out how I can hook a micro controller to that mini USB port so that it can also send and receive data.

When the mini USB is desoldered, there are 5 surface mount spots, 4 of which are for VCC, Ground, Data+, and Data-. I could directly solder 4 wires to those surface mounts, but I have two problems:

- Soldering them is difficult because the surface mounts are very tiny, it requires steadily holding the wires in place, and since the area is so small, the solder crosses over to the other surface mount areas.
- If there is any way, It would be really helpful if the mini USB was still functional

Is there any good way of achieving this?

[image: Mini USB]
[image]

Comment: How's that going to work? You can't just parallel devices on the data lines can you?

Comment: Are you ok with breaking the original device's USB connection?

Comment: OP said "*so that it can **also** send and receive data*".

Comment: @user1850479 as in breaking the mini USB? That wouldn't be a problem as I could just solder a new one I guess

Comment: @Transistor I was thinking of only turning on the micro controller when I need it. If I have to use the microcontroller, I won't have anything plugged in to the mini USB so it wouldn't be receiving data from two different sources at the same time

Comment: What's the impedance the device's USB pins when you have it unpowered?

Comment: tin the wire and the pad, apply flux to the wire or pad, wipe the soldering iron clean, and then reflow with the near-dry soldering iron.

Comment: Can you add a diagram of how you think this should work. I can't figure out whether the device, the micro or the external device is the master and which are the slaves. Given that you've shown a mini-USB port I guess the original device was a slave but now you hope to permanently connect a micro to it as an optional master.

Comment: Why do you want to share the USB with two devices? It can't work if they are both on at the same time obviously

Comment: why dont you make a Y cable that plugs into that port? ... it seems to me that it is what you are trying to do the hard way

Comment: Why did you remove the socket? Can you put it back on?

Answer (score 0):

> Soldering them is difficult because the surface mounts are very tiny, it requires steadily holding the wires in place, and since the area is so small, the solder crosses over to the other surface mount areas.

SMD soldering requires a non-trivial amount of training (and flux). You don't want to train on stuff that needs to be in working condition.

And even if you manage to solder wires to these SMD pads, the result will be rather fragile.

> If there is any way, It would be really helpful if the mini USB was still functional

USB requires a hub once you wanted to connect more than one device to a port.

Also, USB 2.0 high speed data lines are quite sensitive to impedance mismatch, so even just soldering your additional wires could cause USB malfunctions.

Comment: SMD soldering requires practice.  If you have sufficient practice and appropriate solder then you don't need to drown everything in flux.